# How do I suspend an i2c device in Linux from userspace?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, embedded

I am attempting to put a particular device into suspended mode, and have been unable to find a way to do this.
I see in the kernel that a suspend command can be defined, but what is the user space analog to it, if there is one?

In this case, it is to allow me to mask an interrupt in a touchscreen controller before its power is removed.

edited to add additional info:
Additional information: This is for an embedded device, using linux kernel 2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the typical sequence is to send a command to the device to put it into 'suspend' mode, then close the open file descriptor to that device.

Comment: What command would that be? Is suspend controlled through ioctl?

Comment: I don't think an answer exists for this question without a change to the kernel I am using. I am going to give this one to you so I can close the question.